# Docker with mongo user

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a mongodb user for security reason. Now I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:3.3

RUN mongo admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('db').createUser({user: 'test', pwd: 'test'})"
```

When I run docker I get the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.3.5
connecting to: admin
2016-05-17T13:31:07.821+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: Connection refused
2016-05-17T13:31:07.821+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
ERROR: Service 'mongodb' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mongo admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('db').createUser({user: 'test', pwd: 'test'})"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think this is because mongod is not running at this moment?

So how can I create this mongodb user?

Comment: Does this make sense? A user clearly is a configuration thingy and more something for runtime, no?

Comment: You're right. Do you have a solution for this? I have the .env file where I want to place the user and the password.

Comment: @Piu130 sounds like the mongo server is not started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM mongo:3.3
COPY setup.sh /setup.sh
RUN /setup.sh
```

setup.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mongod &

RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo "=> Waiting for confirmation of MongoDB service startup"
    sleep 5
    mongo admin --eval "help" >/dev/null 2>&1
    RET=$?
done

ADMINUSER=user
ADMINPASS=pass

echo "=> Creating an admin user in MongoDB"
mongo admin --eval "db.createUser({user: '$ADMINUSER', pwd: '$ADMINPASS', roles:[{role:'root',db:'admin'}]});"

mongod --shutdown
```

Comment: Thanks :) The tag `3.3.0` doesn't exist in mongo. You should use `3.3`